Can you continue a database log restore after putting an interim restore online?
The normal way to do backups would be:

But can you have your cake and eat it too?
Can you put a DB into WITH RECOVERY state, i.e. bring it online, and still subsequently try to do further differential or log restores on top?


Can you put a DB into WITH RECOVERY state, i.e. bring it online, and still subsequently try to do further differential or log restores on top?

Yes, you'd want to specify that it's for STANDBY and give it an UNDO file location so that the engine can rollback any uncommitted transactions and bring the database to a known good state. The database will be accessible in read-only mode after using the STANDBY option.
Example:
RESTORE LOG MyDatabase FROM DISK = 'x:\Some\Location\File.trn' WITH STANDBY = 'x:\Another\Place\StandbyFileForMyDatabase.tuf'
